# I have extended the default User table named UserProfile and want to access info from Product model but shown integrity error

Tags: python, django, sqlite

## UserProfile table: (Extended table of default User)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE`enter code here`


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    k_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="krishok Name", null=True)
    k_address = models.CharField(max_length=300, default="Goes Krishok Address Here", null=True, blank=True)
    k_national_id_no = models.CharField(default="1", max_length=50)
    k_phone = models.CharField(default="01778956098", max_length=20)
    k_email = models.EmailField(default="xxx@gmail.com", max_length=254)
    k_image = models.ImageField(default = '', upload_to = 'upload/pkrishokImage/')
    national_id = models.ImageField(default= '',upload_to = 'upload/IDImage/')





Product model code:
from Store.models.userprofile import UserProfile
from django.db import models
from .categories import Category
from .unit_type import Unit_Type


class Product(models.Model):
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  default=1)
    unit= models.ForeignKey(Unit_Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  default=1)
    Unit_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    #k_name = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)#this is the problem

    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'upload/productsImg/')

   
    @staticmethod
    def get_all_products():
        return Product.objects.all()

    #Filtering by Category Id: 
    # this method will bring all products by its categoryID
    @staticmethod
    def get_all_products_by_id(category_id):
        if category_id:
            return Product.objects.filter(category = category_id)
        else:
            return Product.get_all_products()
```

#i am trying to get id from extended user table called UserProfile model and want to get access of #all data from Product model, so that i am trying to written my foreignKey at product table from UserProfile table but it's give me integrity error.

Comment: Hi, could you please give us the error as well as the code attempting to access the product model ? Please make it as concise as possible while keeping the error in.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please write a summarized title and put the rest of the explanation in the body.